# Angular 9 - sidenav occupies only content's height

Tags: angular-material, angular9, sidenav

I have browsed throughout this forum trying to find a solution.

My problem is simple, the `mat-sidenav` doesn't straighten through the whole empty height, occupying only the content height.

```html
<div class="main-container" fullscreen>
  <div class="main-banner">
    <button (click)='menuBar.toggle()'>XYZ</button>
    <h1 class='banner-manners'>THIS IS IMPORTANT MESSAGE AREA</h1>
  </div>
  <mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav #menuBar mode='over' class="menu-container">
      <app-menu></app-menu>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content class="content-container">
      <app-kushman></app-kushman>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="main-container">
  <mat-sidenav-container fullscreen>
    <mat-sidenav #menuBar mode='over' class="menu-container">
      <app-menu></app-menu></mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content class="content-container">
      <div class="main-banner">
        <h1 class='banner-manners'>THIS IS IMPORTANT MESSAGE AREA</h1>
        <button (click)='menuBar.toggle()'>XYZ</button>
      </div>
      <app-kushman></app-kushman></mat-sidenav-content>  
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```